# I receive empty object after fetching to react from server

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I send data from server using this code:

```
app.get('/emails', function(req, res) {
var tablica_zadan = [];
   db.collection('emails').find({}).toArray(function(err,docs){
      docs.forEach(function(doc) {
        /*console.log('wypisz numery zadan' + doc.tresc);*/

        tablica_zadan.push(doc);

      });
      /*console.log(tablica_zadan);*/
      res.send(tablica_zadan);
    });

  });

})
```

In my react file I fetch it using code:

```
var docs = fetch('http://localhost:3000/emails')
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.status >= 400) {
            throw new Error("Bad response from server");
        }

        return response.json();
    })
    .then(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

console.log(docs instanceof Array);
console.log(docs);
```

and when I want to print docs by `console.log(docs)` it seems to be empty... 
I have message:

```
Promise {[[PromiseStatus]]: "pending", [[PromiseValue]]: undefined}
```

I don't know how improve it. Please help me.

Comment: By the way, you implemented your error function the wrong way, it should be the 2nd arg to the 'then' function.

Comment: or use `.catch`

Answer (score 2):

`docs` will be a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

To get the actual value, you will need to do the following...

```
docs.then(function(value) {
  console.log(value instanceof Array);
  console.log(value);
});
```